# Concrete5 Blocks not showing saved content in edit

Tags: php, caching, concrete5

I have a weird bug on a website I help build. There are several blocks that when you edit them and add something new it shows up in the text editor and the live website. Then when you go back the edit you made is gone in the text editor but you can see it in the live site. Only a hard refresh will solve the problem but it will happen again. I have exhausted all options. Lets i disabled concrete 5 cache, disabled the javascript, disabled the CSS so I don't know what to do. The website is using the llatest 5.8 version

Comment: Every time you edit any block, you have to "publish changes". I hope you are doing that.